# Angular 7 material tab control with list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have last versions of Angular and last version of material component for it.
I try to render a table which is inside of Tab Control. However I cannot mount sort operation. Please help. Here the code:
View:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="main-content">
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Category Name" name="keyword" [(ngModel)]="keyword">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isActive" name="isActive">Active only</mat-checkbox>
        <button mat-button type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
      <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
        <mat-tab [label]="sysCategory.name" *ngFor="let sysCategory of systemCategories">
          <div>
            <table mat-table matSort matSortDisableClear [dataSource]="dataSource?.items" class="mat-elevation-z4">
              <tr>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Category</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="element.inEditMode">
                      <input matInput placeholder="Category" required maxlength="255" [(ngModel)]="element.name" />
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <span *ngIf="!element.inEditMode">{{element.name}}</span>
                  </td>
                </ng-container>
              </tr>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class CategoriesListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'delete', 'edit'];
  dataSource: ResultsList<CategoryModel>;

  systemCategories: SystemCategoryModel[];
  sysCategoryId: number;
  isActive = true;
  keyword: '';

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort = new MatSort();

  constructor(private systemCategoriesService: DictionaryService, private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.systemCategoriesService.getDictionary<SystemCategoryModel>(SystemCategoriesUrl)
      .subscribe(v => { this.systemCategories = v; });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // S.O.S it doesnt work here for sure!
    // this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.loadGrid());
  }

  onTabChange(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.sysCategoryId = this.systemCategories[tabChangeEvent.index].id;
    this.loadGrid();
  }

  loadGrid() {
    const query = this.createQuery();
    this.categoriesService.load(query).subscribe(v => this.dataSource = v);
  }

  private createQuery(): CategoriesSearchQuery {
    return {
      isActive: this.isActive,
      keyword: this.keyword,
      pageIndex: 0,
      pageSize: 1000,
      sortField: this.sort && this.sort.active || 'name',
      isDesc: this.sort && this.sort.direction === 'desc' || false,
      systemCategoryId: this.sysCategoryId
    };
  }
```

Comment: Might be this: `this.dataSource.sort= this.sort` after assinging the data list to Datasoruce

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, Yeah of course. But... How to add it before?

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz?

Comment: I will try, But Seems it's problematic. Need to spend 1-2-3 hours to mount everything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort = new MatSort();` to simply `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;`.

Additionally you need to assign the `MatSort` to the datasource like this: `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;`, this is usually done in the `ngOnInit()`.

> For more information check out the official [Angular Material
>   examples](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples),
>   there is an example for a table with filtering that should cover your
>   needs.

If you have multiple tables and datasources over multiple tabs I suggest you separate them and not reuse the same datasource and `MatSort` as this will provide some weird behaviour. I would index the data by the current tab you are on and then display the datasource accordingly.

I made a quick and dirty stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-2pxhos?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) to show what this could look like.

Comment: Alas. It doesn't work. As you can find, First I update tabs and then onTabChange I Update tab body.

Comment: Please. Don't send me to angular examples. I was there. That's why I am posting here in StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah and addidionally. Neither this.dataSource.sort nor this.dataSource.items.sort haven't any 'sort' property,

Comment: This is because you are not using a `MatTableDataSource` as describe in the Angular Material documentation. Maybe have a look at the documentation again, [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource).

Comment: Yeah, seems your example is a solution. I will try a little later and of course inform you. Thanks, Fabian

Comment: Sure thing, might not be the best solution but it should give you an idea on where to start to solve your issue. Please update on how you solved it.